# Why aren't negative frequencies folded in reconstruction of the aliased signal?

Tags: fourier-transform, sampling, reconstruction

I'm working on the problem 1.9 from the book *Introduction to Signal Processing* by Sophocles J. Orfanidis. The pdf version and solution is freely available [here](https://www.ece.rutgers.edu/%7Eorfanidi/intro2sp/).

[image]

This is the solution for part a of the exercise:

[image]

I'm a bit confused about the cancelling of two middle terms.

This is my drawing showing my understanding of what they're doing.

[image]

However, why don't you do the same for negative frequencies?

[image]

If you do this then you would get a different result.

**EDIT**: typo - the last term in the image should be 2sin(20πt) instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They **are** doing the same for the negative frequencies, implicitly.

In a problem like this, all signals are real: the input, the sampled signal, and the reconstructed signal. As a consequence, all spectrums are symmetric. If aliasing produces a frequency component at $x$ Hz, then it will also produce one at $-x$ Hz.

Let us take a closer look. We need the following concepts:

1. A sine $$\sin(2\pi f_0 t) = \frac{e^{j2\pi f_0 t}-e^{j2\pi (-f_0) t}}{2j}$$ has frequencies $f_0$ and $-f_0$.
2. A single frequency component $e^{j2\pi f_0 t}$ sampled at frequency $f_s$ produces aliases at frequencies $f_0 + Nf_s$ for all integers $N$.
3. Out of the infinite number of aliases, we're interested in those with the lowest frequency; those are the unique aliases that appear in the Nyquist range $-f_s/2$ to $f_s/2$.

Now, let's focus on $\sin(2\pi f_C t)$ with $f_C=30$. It has two frequencies, $30$ and $-30$. Let us find the aliases of each frequency separately.

- The term $e^{j2\pi 30 t}/2j$ will alias to frequencies $30+40N$, some examples of which are $-90,-50,-10,30,70,110...$. The only value within the Nyquist range corresponds to $N=-1$, so we have $30-40=-10$. We can say that $e^{j2\pi (30) t}$ aliases to $e^{j2\pi (-10) t}/2j$.
- The term $-e^{j2\pi (-30) t}/2j$ will alias to frequencies $-30+40N$. The only alias in the Nyquist range corresponds to $N=1$, where we have $-30+40=10$. We can say that $-e^{j2\pi (-30) t}/2j$ aliases to $-e^{j2\pi (10) t}/2j$.

We can conclude these two things:

1. The aliases are symmetric. This is the reason many textbooks don't calculate every single alias; as soon as you find an alias at $x$, you know there is one at $-x$. This is true only for real signals, which is what we are dealing with in this problem.
2. The sum of the two aliases we calculated is $$ \frac{e^{j2\pi (-10) t}-e^{j2\pi (10) t}}{2j}$$ which implies that $f_0 = -10$. Then, the aliased sine wave is $\sin(2\pi (-10) t) = -\sin(2\pi 10 t)$. This means that aliasing **can** change the sign of the aliased signal.

Coming back to the textbook problem, we see that the term $\sin(2\pi 10t)$ is cancelled by the alias $-\sin(2\pi 10t)$. So, a third conclusion is, aliases may cancel out terms in the input signal!

I guess a fourth and final conclusion might be, avoid aliasing at all costs.

Comment: Can you show explicitly how to get the same result they got taking into account of folding negative frequencies as well? I got a different result.

Comment: There are eight frequencies in the input: $f_A=5$, $f_B=10$, $f_C=30$, and $f_D=45$, and their negatives. $f_A$ and $f_B$ are not aliased. $\pm f_C$ produces aliases at 10 and -10 as explained in my answer. $f_D$ produces one alias at $45-40=5$ and $-f_D$ produces $-45+40=-5$, corresponding to a sine wave of frequency 5.

Comment: I think what may be confusing you is the sign of the sine wave?

Comment: I don't have any problem calculating aliased frequencies like that. I want to know how would you reconstruct the aliased signal ya(t) from these  aliased frequencies. In the image I sent I did calculate all folding frequencies and then reconstruct the signal but got a different result than their answer.

Comment: I think you're mixing up $sin(-2\pi f_0 t)$ with $e^{-j2\pi f_0 t}$. A single impulse in the frequency domain (as you've drawn it) corresponds to $e^{j2\pi f_0 t}$, which is only half of $sin(2\pi f_0 t)$. So @MBaz is correct that the negative frequencies mirror the positive ones exactly, so you only have to think about the frequencies of the $sin(x)$, not both components. Recall the definition of $sin(x)$ in terms of complex exponentials: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry

Comment: @Gillespie me? Can you show me where I mixed them. I know Euler's formula and sin, cos in terms of complex exponentials.

Comment: @hana I've expanded my answer, please let me know if it helps.

Comment: `The term ej2πfCt/2j will alias to fC−40=−10fC−40=−10, becoming ej2π(−10)t/2j` 
Can you explain this? Why −10 instead of −fC+40=10? The first term has positive frequency so should it be 10Hz?

Comment: For example with `fDa = ±10` then both `sin(20πt)` and `sin(-20πt)=-sin(20πt)` give you the same frequencies components.

Comment: Frequency $f_0$ will be aliased to $f_0 + Nf_s$ for integer $N$. You are interested in aliases in the range from $-f_s/2$ to $f_s/2$. 30 Hz aliases to $\ldots,-50,-10,30,70,\ldots$, so you keep $-10$. Likewise, -30 Hz will alias to $\ldots,-110,-70,-30,10,50,\ldots$, so you keep $10$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing

Comment: $\sin(20t)$ and $-\sin(20t)$ have the same frequency components, but with different sign (phase).

Comment: You still didn't explain the question. I know the folding and what to keep. The confusing part is convert from the frequencies to sine waves. 
As I asked above, `the term ej2πfCt/2j will alias to fC−40=−10fC−40=−10, becoming ej2π(−10)t/2j` Can you explain why −10 instead of −fC+40=10? The first term has positive frequency so should it be 10Hz?
You could assign f0 = 10 and got −sin(20 pi t).

Comment: I already explained: 30 Hz aliases to -50, -10, 30, 70... so you keep -10.

Comment: For the same reasoning, -30Hz  aliases to `-70, -30, 10, 50, 90, 130` so why don't you keep 10Hz (I'm talking about the 10Hz which is in the nyqyst bandwidth orginally)?

Comment: I think I found the answer. The drawing of fourier above is similar to the book but now I find it confusing. If I redraw it including phase as below I got the correct answer. 
https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-07ddbd38436f36e95bbac65c545f21d4

Comment: @hana Your drawing (of the spectrum) is mistaken in the sense that all impulses seem to have positive weights: actually $\sin(\omega_0 t) \leftrightarrow -\frac{\pi}{j} \delta(\omega + \omega_0) + \frac{\pi}{j} \delta(\omega - \omega_0) $. as you can see, the impulse at the negative frequency has negative (and complex) weight wrt the impulse at the positive frequency. Therefore when your impulse at + D is folded onto impulse at -B, they cancel. and so for the symmetric impulse at +B, folded from -D... This explains how they cancel in the frequency domain.

Comment: @Fat32 I just realized that. I followed that way of drawing from the book but then I got confused.

Comment: @haha yes I saw that you realized the mistake, before putting my comment, but anyway, MBaz is also teling the same thing

Comment: I saw that he/she got the same result but I still don't understand how MBaz assign fc-40 for the first bullet point and -fc +40 for the second bullet point. Can you also assign it the other way?

Comment: @hana I've expanded the explanation in the bullets. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Just want to mention that I probably wrongly blamed the book on drawing fourier plot wrong. Examples in the book is for cosine instead of sine and the drawing is good for cosine.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that $\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$, which is a standard [trigonometry identity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities). Thus, $\sin(20\pi t) + \sin(-20\pi t) = \sin(20\pi t) - \sin(20\pi t) = 0$

Comment: well, I think you misundestood my quesiton! I, of course, know baisc math like that. My question is more about the concept rather than math.

Comment: Sorry, when you said you were confused by the canceling of the middle terms, I took it literally. MBaz's answer is correct.

Comment: No worries, MBaz's answer doesn't show how to get the result taking  negative frequencies folding into account.